# Early chapter epigram: “Your buffalo may lie down in my wallow.” From what S-F novel?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Long, long ago I possessed for a short time, and then lost before reading, a science-fiction paperback whose story concerned linguistics. One of its early chapters, perhaps the first, had for its epigram the sentence, “Your buffalo may lie down in my wallow.” Can someone supply the title of the novel?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/list/show/22451.Science_Fiction_using_Languages_or_Linguistics_as_a_Plot_Device

Comment: How long ago was "long, long ago"? Before 1950?

Comment: I don't know how far back "long, long ago" is, but the portion about linguistics reminds me of the Sheila Finch novel "Guild of the XenoLinguists".  The book came out in 2007, but I believe a number of the stories from the novel were published before that in various forms. Perhaps one of those stories is what you are seeking?  The website shows a cover:   http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/f/sheila-finch/guild-of-xenolinguists.htm